# mysqli_stmt expected query

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

I'm having issues with the following code

```
function doesNotExist($field, $userInput){

    $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","adminP",base64_decode("MTEyODMx"), "Peter");
    $sql = "SELECT". $field ." FROM `accounts` WHERE". $field ." = (?)";

    $stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, $sql);
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 's', $userInput);
    Print("Test");
    mysqli_Stmt_execute($stmt);
    $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
    $row_cnt = mysqli_num_rows($result);
    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
    mysqli_close($conn);
    if($row_cnt == 0){
        return true;
    }
    else{
        Print ("Invalid " . $field);
        return false;
    }
}
```

And it's given me the errors

> Warning: mysqli_stmt_bind_param() expects parameter 1 to be
>   mysqli_stmt, boolean given in C:\wamp\www\signup.php on line 61
>
> Warning: mysqli_stmt_execute() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_stmt,
>   boolean given in C:\wamp\www\signup.php on line 63
>
> Warning: mysqli_stmt_get_result() expects parameter 1 to be
>   mysqli_stmt, boolean given in C:\wamp\www\signup.php on line 64
>
> Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result,
>   null given in C:\wamp\www\signup.php on line 65
>
> Warning: mysqli_stmt_close() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_stmt,
>   boolean given in C:\wamp\www\signup.php on line 66

I'm creating a stmt with

> $stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, $sql);

but have no idea why it's not recognizing it

Comment: Ask `mysqli_error` after the `_prepare` on where you missed a space.

Comment: As per the usual - one or more of your DB calls has failed, you FAILED to check for failure, and now your failures have caused further failures as your code blunders onwards with invalid data. Your $sql statement is also completely invalid, because you'v failed to put spaces around the variables you're inserting, leading to ugliness like `SELECTfoo FROM ... WHEREbar = ?`

Answer (score 3):

The [manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) is helpful:

> mysqli_prepare() returns a statement object or FALSE if an error occurred.

Use `mysqli_error($conn)` to get the error reason. My guess is that it's because you don't have spaces after your SELECT and WHERE, so you're getting SQL syntax errors, unless $field definitely starts with a space. And start using error handling in your code!